# Was the victory mentioned in the Star Wars title crawl mentioned before Rogue One?

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes

The title crawl of the original 1977 *Star Wars* film mentions that the rebel alliance

> have won their first victory against the evil Galactic Empire.

[image: title crawl]

The 2016 film *Rogue One* identifies this victory as the Battle of Scarif.

Between 1977 and 2016 had any mention ever been made in any media either in or out of universe on what the victory in the original title crawl was?

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Toprawa - Not explained by Lucas, but subsequently added in the radio drama, then retconned out of existence by Disney